# Magento_Checkout::js/components.phtml invalid template

Tags: magento-2.1, error, template

I get this error in the system.log:

```
   [2018-03-13 16:20:04] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'Magento_Checkout::js/components.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'checkout_page_head_components' [] []
```

It's never good to see any error regarding the checkout, has anyone came across it and knows what is the cause and how to resolve it?

Running **Magento ver. 2.1.8** and **Varnish** using **Linux**.

Also, found this which can be related:

```
[2018-03-14 09:03:15] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'checkout.header.wrapper'. [] []
```

Edit:

This is the path to my `components.phtml` file in my custom theme:

```
/http/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/Magento_Checkout/templates/js/components.phtml
```

My `layout/default.xml` file:

```
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_page_head_components" template="Magento_Checkout::js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
```

My `layout/checkout_cart_configure.xml file`:

```
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_cart_configure_head_components" template="Magento_Checkout::js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Are you using linux?

Comment: I am using linux.

Comment: see updated anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error can appear when the **Magento** cannot find the template file. Please check if you have any typos in the folder names and check if the folders are the correct case.(Example: On linux **"view"** and **"View"** folders are different)

**EDIT:**

if you want to override the template "**components.phtml**" you can use the fallback system. You don't need the layouts. Just make sure you have the same paths.

### Override templates

The fallback scheme for templates is the following (module context is always known for them):

Current theme templates:

```
 <theme_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/templates
```

Ancestors themes templates, recursively, until a theme with no ancestor is reached:

```
<parent_theme_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/templates
```

Module templates:

```
<module_dir>/view/frontend/templates
```

So if you need to customize a certain template, you need to create an overriding one with the same name in the ../templates/ directory in the theme module files. Where  is the path to the original template.

For example, if you must override the **/view/frontend/templates/category/widget/link/link_block.phtml** template, the  is **category/widget/link/**

Look [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html) and [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html#theme-inherit-templates).

Comment: should it be with a capital if I am using linux?

Comment: it should be "view" with a lower case "v"

Comment: can you please share the file path to the components.phtml in your custom module/theme?

Comment: This configuration came with the theme I have installed. Also, looking at the file in vendor and the one from the theme, they look exactly the same. Should I still go and overwrite this file or I can remove all the entries of this file in the custom theme?

Comment: i cannot know for sure if you should remove or keep that file because i don't know the reason/purpose the people who created the theme had when they worked on the custom theme.